# Is there a by-group interaction issue after the Box-Cox transformation?

Tags: lme4-nlme, data-transformation, boxcox-transformation

I've come across a question that has me a bit stumped and hope to seek your valuable insights. Specifically, I've been working with the Box-Cox Transformation to normalize dependent variables within each group for each language. The cross-language main effect remains significant in a linear mixed-effect model. My concern is whether the by-group interaction might be an artifact of the overall differences across groups, as discussed by Faust et al. (1999). I would greatly appreciate any guidance or thoughts you might have on this matter.

Here are my Box-Cox Transformation codes:

```r
model1 = lm(response  ~ Group * Language * AOA, data = L1)
library(MASS)
bc = boxcox(model1,lambda=seq(-1,1,by = 0.05), plotit = TRUE)
lambda <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]
L1$response_BC = (L1$ response ^ lambda-1)/lambda
```

Here is my model code:

```r
lmer_model1 <- lmer(response_BC ~ Group * Language * AOA + 
    (1 | participants), data = data, REML = TRUE )
```

Group and language are categorical variables: **Group:** French vs German; **Language**: Native language vs Second language. **AOA** is a continuous variable indicating the age at which the participants learned the word.

Here are my results:

[image]

As you can see the **Group** was significant. I was asked whether the significance observed in **GroupGerman:AOA** is an artifact of the overall differences across groups (Faust et al., 1999). Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain your issue in a little more detail, and provide a link to the paper? Also, how exactly are you Box-Cox-transforming your data (same transformation for all groups, or separate by groups, and how do you deal with covariates?). Note that normality of residuals or of data within groups is nice but not always required, especially not for larger samples. Finally, Box-Cox can absolutely change conclusions, since you are now modeling on nonlinearly transformed data.

Comment: Why are you doing Box Cox transformations at all? In addition to the points @StephanKolassa made, there are methods that don't rely on normal residuals at all. Two examples are robust regression and quantile regression.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your response! Here is the link to the article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12712633_Individual_differences_in_information-processing_rate_and_amount_Implications_for_group_differences_in_response_latency. I have made a sincere effort to read it, but it is challenging for me....

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you for your response! My data exhibits a right-side tail (positively skewed), so I was advised to use a box-cox transformation to normalize the data, enabling analysis using a linear mixed model. Am I not supposed to do this?

Comment: Well, it's not necessary. Partly because, now that we have fast computers and good algorithms, methods that were computationally prohibitive are now easy. But that knowledge filters very slowly to the people teaching stats courses in non-math departments.

Comment: @PeterFlom I see. Is it possible to apply the lmer model without normalizing the data, or would additional processing be required? Do you have any suggestions regarding the above question? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible to use lmer without normalizing the data.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you very much!!

Comment: I beg to differ with @Peter.  In particular, I would be *very* interested in knowing exactly how "fast computers and good algorithms" will cope with this particular problem of handling a skewed conditional response in a *mixed* model.  A Box-Cox transformation can be simple, readily interpreted, parsimonious, and effective.  And if it's not, then you can move on to more complicated approaches.

Comment: @whuber Fast computers do it by allowing models such as quantile regression.  Box Cox transformations are usually UNinterpretable. The square root of IQ?  How about the 2/3 power of weight?   Quantile regression on the median is much easier to interpret than that.  (And quantile based mixed models are available).

Comment: @Peter Quantile regression does something quite different from a mixed model.  Simple powers often do have simple interpretations.  Look at it the other way: suppose the data are supplied as the 3/2 power of weight: the Box-Cox transformation of power 2/3 will convert that back to weight itself.  *That is one of the main points:* the way in which data are originally expressed is not necessarily meaningful or useful.  Achieving a re-expression of the numbers that provides insight is doing something that cannot be replicated by any amount of quantile regression (and is far more parsimonious).

Comment: @whuber We will, I think, just have to agree to disagree. "Weight" is meaningful.  The 2/3 power of weight is not.  Personally, I think BoxCox is going to disappear. It's no longer needed.

Comment: @Peter In many applications the 2/3 power of weight is a proxy for the 2/3 power of a *volume,* which is readily interpretable as an *area.*  Disagree or not, I will continue to object to your constant negative comments about transformations because -- as I have repeatedly stated -- I think they are misinformed and mislead people.  (I do want to be clear that re-expressions of data are no panacea: but they have a rightful place in any analyst's toolkit and cannot be replaced by any amount of computing power.)

Comment: @whuber Do you have any suggestions regarding my above question? Thank you!

Comment: I view this kind of automated, maximum likelihood use of Box-Cox transformations rather dimly because it is contrary to its original motivation.  I have contributed many posts about this, so if you would like to learn more, see the results of [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+Box-Cox).

Comment: @whuber thank you!